# HP P1005 laserjet problem in Lubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10

I have manually installed HP P1005 laserjet in my PC and it has been functioning very well.
The other day when switched on my PC a message on the desktop asked me to upgrade software for the printer. So I did, unfortenately. After that I can not print graphical barcodes, printing text is no problem. Where the barcode should be, the paper is blank. I am not willing to manually reinstall my laserjet again. Using Synaptic I have reinstalled all software for the printer, but no luck - What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try with Installing the HP printer drivers again :

```
sudo apt-get install hp-ppd hpijs hpijs-ppds hplip hplip-cups hplip-data hplip-dbg hplip-doc hplip-gui djtools
```